# IntelliJ IDEA: how to make the java bytecode files (.class) compiled from the source files (.java) be in the same directory as the source files?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am working on a project that requires the java bytecode files (.class) to be in the same directory as the source java files (.java).

Is there a certain option I can choose to make it so that I can specify that a directory is both a source file and an output file on IntelliJ?

**In other words, how do I make .class and .java files both be in the top-level directory?**

I am currently working on IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.1.2.

Comment: Why is it that you want to do this? It isn't typical, and for good reasons.

Comment: I need to access the .class file. I am working on a very odd project where I read a .class file from the top-level directory. Is there a solution? I realize it isn't typical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to access the .class file, you can read it as resource using ClassLoader like:

```java
Thread.currentThread()
    .getContextClassLoader().getResource("my/package/MyClass.class");
```